# How to proceed from G3 to G4 - Candidate Elimination

Tags: machine-learning

**How to proceed from G3 to G4?**

I'm trying to apply **candidate elimination** for the following table and achieve specific and generic boundaries.

[image]

```
S0 : <0 0 0 0 0 0>     G0: <? ? ? ? ? ?>

Negative D1 : <Green Normal Yes String Good Same>
S1 = S0
G1 = <Dry ? ? ? ? ?> 
     <? Hot ? ? ? ?> 
     <? ? No ? ? ?> 
     <? ? ? Normal ? ?>
     <? ? ? ? Avg ?>
     <? ? ? ? ? Change>

Negative D2 : <Green Normal Yes Strong Avg Same>
S2 = S0
G2 = <Dry ? ? ? ? ?> 
     <? Hot ? ? ? ?> 
     <? ? No ? ? ?> 
     <? ? ? Normal ? ?> 
     <? ? ? ? ? Change>

Positive D3 : <Dry Normal No Normal Avg Change>
S3 = <Dry Normal No Normal Avg Change>
G3 = <Dry ? ? ? ? ?>  
     <? ? No ? ? ?> 
     <? ? ? Normal ? ?> 
     <? ? ? ? ? Change>

Negative : D4 :<Dry Hot No Normal Good Change>
```

If I remove dissimilar ones from G, all elements will be removed.

**How to proceed from G3 to G4?**

Answer (score 0):

Go by the algorithm of [Candidate Elimination](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~pardo/courses/mmml/lectures/NU%20EECS%20349%20Fall%2009%20topic%201%20-%20version%20spaces.pdf#page=23). According to the algorithm, if negative, first remove inconsistent hypothesis from S.

Therefore, `S4 :<D N N ? A ?>`

As for `G`, you have to remove each inconsistent hypothesis, and add the ones that match the algorithm.

[image]

As you can see, all the hypothesis in current `G3` are inconsistent, therefore we remove each of them.

And then we add all minimal specializations of them (i.e. the combinations of 2 items). The combinations must satisfy `S` while **NOT** satisfying `D` (since `D` is negative)

That basically means to consider all 2-item combinations in `S4`, and remove ones that are inconsistent with `D4`.

`Negative : D4 :<Dry Hot No Normal Good Change>`

`S4 :<D N N ? A ?>`

And one combination is `<D N ? ? ? ?>` and that is consistent with `D` so we keep it.

Another combination is `<D ? N ? ? ?>` but it satisfies `D` (therefore inconsistent because `D` is negative). So we don't keep it.

Likewise `G4` can be calculated as

```
 G4 : { <D N ? ? ? ?>   <D ? ? ? A ?>
        <? N N ? ? ?>   <? N ? N ? ?>   <? N ? ? ? C>
        <? ? N ? A ?>   
        <? ? ? N A ?>
        <? ? ? ? A C>
      }
```